# Industry standard for managing Nuget packages within the enterprise

Tags: nuget, repository, standards, enterprise

I have a situation where we have multiple C# projects that use similar set of Nuget packages (ex. Newton Json, Microsoft Compilers and CodeDom, Owin, log4net, jQuery, EntityFramework etc.)

I am trying to see how we can have a shared location for all Nuget packages to reduce the footprint of those binaries in Git, having a single repo for them by centralizing them in one place.

One option I found is to use Nuget.config in each project with repositoryPath set to point at the shared location. This works great for adding/upgrading/restoring Nuget packages in the project but it is not very clean when a package gets removed from one project but is still required in a different one. Basically the package will get removed from the shared location and the change is committed to Git, then when the other project requires it, it would get restored and added back to Git. Not a perfect solution in my mind.

I have a two part question:
1. Is there a way to improve the above workflow when packages get removed?
2. What is the industry standard for handling third party libraries delivered via Nuget? Or if there is none, can you share your experience handling Nuget packages across multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the concern lies with the footprint/organization of the Git repository, maybe you can do a .git ignore for the dependencies folders to prevent git from committing them into the repositories. When you need to build the projects from source, just do a dotnet /nuget restore to get the dependencies from the source you configured in the Nuget.config
2. Not sure if it is the industry standard, but we  host our own Nuget server to control the libraries that the different teams can use. Microsoft has an article on [Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

Hope it helps.